# drupal install module: does not contain any .info files

Tags: drupal, installation

I'm developing a custom module for drupal. On installation drupal says: **does not contain any .info files.**

This is the info file:

```
    ; $Id$
name = Cookiedo
description = Dop default cookie module
core = 7.x
package = Dop development

version = 1.0.0

files[] = cookiedo.install
files[] = cookiedo.module
files[] = cookiedo.admin.inc

configure = admin/config/system/cookiedo
```

do you see any flaws? Any ideas on how to solve this? Im compressing the files with GUI tar to a .tgz file. And yes, the compressed file contains the .info file..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

found the solution:

**compress the whole folder**  instead of compressing all files